# R Markdown file does not display plots in Github .md file

Tags: r, github, plot, r-markdown

Created a R Markdown analysis in RStudio, and used Knitr to create an HTML file and preserve the .md file. The local HTML file is rendered as expected; plots and formatting. But when I push to my Github repo, the plots are not displaying: https://github.com/GoodTimeWagon/RepData_PeerAssessment1/blob/master/Reproducible_Research_Peer_Assessment_1.md

In place of a plot it says -
 *![](Reproducible_Research_Peer_Assessment_1_files/figure-html/histogram daily steps-1.png)*

I've pushed the image files as well as the markdown, so I'm really at a loss. Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: Possibly due to the spaces in the image file name?

Comment: That did it! Thank you!!